# Ativar o select somente quando o option do select anterior for escolhido

Tags: php, javascript

Pessoal eu preciso que o select 2 referente a unidade de retirada fique ativado apenas se o a option do select 1 for igual a "Retirada". Conseguem me ajudar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input" disabled>
    <br><br>
    <label>Selecione a opção de recebimento do pedido</label>
    <select id="options" onchange="verifica(this.value)">
    <option value="2">1 - Delivery</option>
    <option value="3">2 - Retirada</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Selecione a unidade que irá retirar o do pedido</label>
    <select id="options" onchange="verifica(this.value)">
    <option value="2">1 - Unidade </option>
    <option value="3">2 - Unidade</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se o valor é igual `3` coloque ou remova o atributo `disabled`, não precisa chamar a função no segundo select, seguindo o código que fez:

```
function verifica(v) {
  if(v == 3)document.getElementById("options2").removeAttribute("disabled"); 
  else document.getElementById("options2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input" disabled>
    <br><br>
    <label>Selecione a opção de recebimento do pedido</label>
    <select id="options" onchange="verifica(this.value)">
    <option value="2">1 - Delivery</option>
    <option value="3">2 - Retirada</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Selecione a unidade que irá retirar o do pedido</label>
    <select id="options2" disabled>
    <option value="2">1 - Unidade </option>
    <option value="3">2 - Unidade</option>
    </select>
```

Id é um campo único, não use para mais de um elemento.

Fiddlw: https://jsfiddle.net/7shLcpvk/

Comment: Legal! Pode ainda envolver o select 2 em uma div e controlar a exibição... fica mais amigável para o usuário...

Comment: É uma pergunta ou afirmação? hehe

Comment: Rss afirmação com sugestão de melhoria, para nosso amigo Matheus tentar fazer ;)

Comment: Mas pelo jeito ele está ausente hehe

Comment: Shoow. Muito obrigado, consegui fazer com a ajuda de vocês.